# Name of partial derivatives where the order of differentiation can be reversed.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, terminology

Is there a name given to partial differential equations of the form: $$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}}$$ Not asking for any kind of proof, just specifically wondering if there is a name given to PDE's that satisfy this condition.

Comment: That is a smoothness criterion that is basically put on all multivariable functions.

Comment: I understand Clairaut's theorem is the condition for this commutativity but I haven't seen a name given to functions that satisfy this condition that specifically contrasts them to those that don't. I was looking for a name in the same way we call differential equations "linear" if they have certain features.

Comment: This cannot be interesting as a pde because Clairaut says that all nicely smooth functions satisfy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the equality
$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}},$$
interpreted as a pde, have no special name because it is not commonly interpreted as a pde.

On the other hand, understood as "a condition on" or "a property of" a certain function $F$, the said equality is usually referred to as

- [Equality of mixed partial derivatives](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22equality+of+mixed+partial+derivatives%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNRV9293wM3aNTPr7DSScvfB9ZFr4w:1574871251076&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw2PLL5IrmAhX-IbkGHYEfAjYQ_AUoAXoECAwQCQ&cshid=1574871472429431&biw=1366&bih=625).
- [Symmetry of second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).
- [Symmetry of the hessian matrix](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22symmetry+of+the+hessian+matrix%22&sxsrf=ACYBGNQyLPv-lAMmp0VUPf85eNmXK8_awQ:1574870689435&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi334rA4ormAhWHGrkGHQ-UAzYQ_AUICSgA&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1).

Answer (score 2):

It is known as Clairaut's  theorem.

Suppose F is defined on a disk D that contains the point (a,b).  If the functions $$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$$ and $$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}} $$ are both continuous on D, then $$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}(a,b)=\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}}(a,b)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've seen Clairaut's theorem referenced as the condition but never an actual name given to PDEs that commute like this. I was wondering if there was a name like "continuous" PDE or something like that but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @Charlie  We simply say partial derivatives commute which is very helpful in finding higher partials in the most convenient way by rearranging if necessary.